# Display and show message on jsp recieved in onMessage() method of messagelistener

Tags: java, spring, activemq-classic

i have onmessage method in my controller for recieving messages now i want to show that message on jsp,how cn it be done,message can easily be printed on console.

Comment: This question is much to vague and need more context.

Comment: hi tim,i m trying to develope a chat app using activemq and spring,in which i have a chat window so when i press submit button the text is displayed on chat window sinse onSubmit message is called return modelandview and i show same jsp so message display on window(jsp)bt for recieving message ia m overriding onMessage method of messagelistener interface,which has void returntype so i cnt return modelandview so not able to display recieved 1 on window

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to read up on how web applications are constructed.

Basically, JMS/ActiveMQ provides web applications with asynchronous data. In most cases, you would have the messages processed and put down into a database. Then you can use the newly populated data to build up your JSP web site (when the user reloads it).

JMS -> Your App -> DB  <-> Controller/JSP <-> Web Site

Doing something like you ask for, printing data on a user web site at the moment a message arrives is possible but out of scope for this question, since it has more to do with technologies such as [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) (ajax/push) and the servlet side of things along with some routing logic. Asking this question, you probably shouldn't even think about it (yet).